# How is Max's Interceptor still running?

Tags: vehicles, mad-max, engineering

I am not referring to the fact that the Interceptor has been wrecked more than once.  It is perfectly possible to salvage an engine from a wrecked car provided the engine block itself has not suffered damage.  The idea of rebuilding a car is not too incomprehensible to me.  The problem I have is how the engine itself has managed to survive operating in its environment.

That V8 engine has a freaking supercharger, and it is used on road and off road (mostly off) in a desert, and has been for at least several years now.  That supercharger is going to suck up a huge amount of sand directly into that engine and utterly ruin it.  How has that engine not been completely destroyed yet?

Comment: You mean in Mad Max 2?

Comment: I mean in the franchise in general.  So everything except Thunderdome.  We are all going to have to get beyond Thunderdome.

Comment: It's got a plot filter on the intake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

George Miller has said in [an interview](https://www.fandango.com/movie-news/interview-director-george-miller-answers-all-your-big-mad-max-fury-road-questions-749278), the films aren't one complete story line. They're more like stories people tell in a post apocalyptic world of the Road Warrior called Max

The Interviewer asks:

> What would you call this film? A sequel? A reboot?

Miller Replies

> I like to call it a revisit.

and

> I can’t even work out the chronology of the first, second and third, let alone the fourth thirty years later.

It's up to you how you think the films fit together, the fact that two different actors have played Max and the same actors have played different characters in different movies: Gyrocopter pilot (Road Warrior) and the Pilot (Thunderdome), or Toecutter (Mad Max) and Immortan Joe (Fury Road); suggests they're not one continuous timeline.

I can't find the interview now (It might have been on the fury road blue-ray extras) but I remember one of the staff remarking on how much damage the sand did to the engines during filming.